# Nuxt head() does not wait asyncData response for head

Tags: vue.js, url-routing, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt code like this

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div>Hello Nuxt</div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
const fetchTheme = () => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        title: "Fetched Title"
      });
    }, 100);
  });
};

export default {
  async asyncData() {
    const theme = await fetchTheme();
    return theme;
  },

  head() {
    if (this.theme) {
      return {
        title: this.theme.title
      };
    } else {
      return {
        title: "Default title"
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

While I do view source, it gives 'Default title' but I need the title fetched from API
Here is Code [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-esfdr)

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/) on asyncData:

> Nuxt.js will automatically merge the returned object with the component data.

That means that what you're doing:

```
  async asyncData() {
    const theme = await fetchTheme();
    return theme;
  }
```

is analogous to this:

```
  async asyncData() {
    const theme = await fetchTheme();
    return {
      title: theme.title
    };
  }
```

Which means that the title is accessible by doing `this.title` instead of `this.theme.title`.

To fix this, simply modify the return format of asyncData, to return an object that has a theme property:

```
  async asyncData() {
    const theme = await fetchTheme();
    return {
       theme
    };
  }
```

This will properly add the `theme` property to the `data` property of the component.